# Remove dictionary from another dictionary (strange behavior in python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dict

```
runde = {
    "A": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "B": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "C": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "D": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
}

bilete = {
    "B": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "C": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
}
```

I want to substract bilete from runde, with result

```
runde = {
    "A": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
}
```

The code

```
for key in runde:
    if key in bilete:
        b = bilete[key]
        for a in b:
            runde[key].remove(a)
```

This code works fine, but in my situation, after first .remove, the result is

```
{'A': ['4, 5, 6'],'B': ['4, 5, 6'],'C': ['4, 5, 6'],'D': ['4, 5, 6']}
```

after second .remove the result is

```
{'A': [],'B': [],'C': [],'D': []}
```

and then I get the error ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

This is my situation, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
import pickle
# here is my variables saved: import.pkl
# https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SbJm9J5dFQgc1H6m8C6epqDLAs2m15lS/view?usp=sharing
with open('import.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    runde, bilete = pickle.load(f)
for key in runde:
    if key in bilete:
        b = bilete[key]
        for a in b:
            runde[key].remove(a)
```

Comment: Never modify structures you are currently iterating over.

Comment: I don't get the problems you claim to see, nor do I get the error. I think the data you claim to have is not what you have at all.

Comment: @AKX Its nothing to do with modifying the collection you are iterating over. The processing implied above does not affect the keys, which is what it being iterated over.

Comment: You can try: `for key in list(runde.keys())`

Comment: Can you print what exactly you are getting after reading from `import.pkl`

Comment: Also, why are you getting a third `.remove()`? There are only two keys in `bilete`.

Comment: @quamrana I save my variables in import.pkl

Comment: I'm guessing that whatever is in `import.pkl` has linked references. This is proved by what happens after the second `.remove()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I type in this code:

```py
runde = {
    "A": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "B": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "C": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "D": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
}

bilete = {
    "B": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
    "C": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"],
}

for key in runde:
    if key in bilete:
        b = bilete[key]
        for a in b:
            runde[key].remove(a)

print(runde)
```

I get this output:

```py
{'A': ['1, 2, 3', '4, 5, 6'], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'D': ['1, 2, 3', '4, 5, 6']}
```

I'm trying to guess exactly what data you have, but so far I haven't been able to reproduce your exact symptoms.

If, however, I type in this code:

```py
first = "1, 2, 3"
second = "4, 5, 6"
coll = [first, second]
runde = {
    "A": coll,
    "B": coll,
    "C": coll,
    "D": coll,
}

bilete = {
    "B": coll,
    "C": coll,
}

for key in runde:
    if key in bilete:
        b = bilete[key]
        for a in b:
            runde[key].remove(a)
            print(runde)

print(runde)
```

I get this output:

```
{'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'D': []}
```

and no error.

Also, if I insert this code before all the loops:

```
import copy
for k in runde:
    runde[k] = copy.deepcopy(runde[k])
```

then the output returns to the desired output.

Comment: And why runde["B"].remove("1, 2, 3"), remove "1, 2, 3" from all dictionary and not only from key B?

Comment: Its because, as I show, the collections are the same collection. When you remove from one, you remove from all because they are the same. Also, see my second update.

Comment: Works fine now! Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks @quamrana, I recall theory now, after your post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting different dictionaries while reading

```
with open('import.pkl', 'rb') as f:
runde, bilete = pickle.load(f)
```

The code you have posted, should return correct result.